# No DisplayLink-enabled device detected

Tags: multiple-monitors, displayport, usb-c, displaylink

I am using the VisionTek VT8000 quad display dock to hook into 4 LG 35WN65C's (each monitor using displayport cables to the dock) and then using a usb-c cable from the dock to a usb-c to displayport adaptor and then a displayport to mini DisplayPort cable to my 2015 MacBook Pro.

I have installed the latest version of DisplayLink Manager (and the login addition), but whenever I plug into the hub it does not detect any of the monitors and the monitors go into sleep mode. I have tried a fresh install of the program and restarting the monitors and my computer (after the install) and nothing has popped up.

The monitors each work individually if I plug in the mini display port to display port straight into my computer but that only gets me to 2 monitors.

Could anyone please help me figure out what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FAQ at [VisionTek / VT8000](https://visiontek.com/products/vt8000-quad-display-4k-usb-3-0-usb-c-docking-station-with-100w-power-delivery):

> **My displays are not working while connected to the VT8000.**
>
> - Please install the latest DisplayLink drivers from this link:  https://www.displaylink.com/downloads
> - Make sure all cables are connected to the Dock and that the dock is powered on.
> - Ensure the displays in the Display Settings arrangement are not set to Disconnect by default

=> The last aspect you do not describe in your question.

Your computer should also fullfill the hardware requirements:

> **Dock to System Connection**
>
> USB 3.0 Type A
> USB-C 3.1
> Thunderbolt™ 3
>
> *System with USB-C 3.1 Gen2 port that supports USB-C Charging recommended for best performance.

I Do not know these Macs, but a quick search implied to me that your *"2015 MacBook Pro"* just supports *"Thunderbold 2"*.

*=> I don't think, your "2015 MacBook Pro" is supported by the "Visiontek VT8000" for **full product support.***

EDIT: You feedback shows, that the VT8000 will do the best that the offered connection is capable of.

Please note that due to the different port specs you might see some limitations:

| Port | Max. Speed |
| --- | --- |
| USB 3.0, USB 3.1 Gen 1 | 5 GBit/s |
| USB 3.1 Gen 2 | 10 GBit/s |
| USB 3.2 | 20 GBit/s |
| Thunderbolt 2 | 20 GBit/s |
| Thunderbolt 3 | 40 GBit/s |
| HDMI 2.0 | 14.4 GBit/s |

*Regarding the possible speed of HDMI and the maximum speed of USB 3.0, you should try to connect via your Thunderbolt port to have more bandwidth available for your four 4K-displays.*
See also the [table: HDMI Refresh frequency limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Refresh_frequency_limits_for_common_resolutions#Refresh_frequency_limits_for_common_resolutions)

The bandwidth problem will be compensated by the compression of DisplayLink up to a certain degree, but the compression efficiency is depending on the displayed content.

Comment: The MacBook Pro 2015 has two USB 3.0 Type A ports and when using a USB-C to USB 3.0 adaptor it works. Thanks for telling me what system connections are required, I had figured using DisplayPort would have provided more information (for my computer for the displays).